# html file tables scraping to csv all data will be squeezed in the same grid

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently doing a html form crawler. I can currently print all forms, but when exporting to a csv file, all data will be squeezed in the same grid.

code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr7Oi.png)

Comment: do you look at your dataframe before? I am pretty sure your dataframe has 1 grid only. That's why. Right now you create the Dataframe only from 1 BIG string. I guess you want to do it from a list or a dict. Can you show a short output example of the CSV or the dataframe ?

Comment: do you want 1 row per album ? 1 column per Album ? How is supposed to be the Output ?

Comment: I want 1row per album，but I don’t know how to do it first.

Comment: 1 row per album and 1 column per album ?

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If you want 1 column per Album and 1 row per Album I think this code should do the trick

```py
import pandas as pd

albumsaved = []
for record in soup.findAll('tr'):
    albumdata =""
    for data in record.findAll('td'):
        albumdata += "," + data.text
    albumsaved.append(albumdata[1:])
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(albumsaved, columns=None)
data_frame.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Now this code can export data 1 row per Album,but it can't do 1 column per Album